# How to increment Alphanumeric value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that contains more than 200 items. I want to list them and assign a group code to every 5 items.
For example

```
GroupCode    Item
GC-01        ITEM-A
GC-01        ITEM-B
GC-01        ITEM-C
GC-01        ITEM-D
GC-01        ITEM-E
GC-02        ITEM-F
GC-02        ITEM-G
GC-02        ITEM-H
```

After every 5 items GroupCode should add 1 in numeric part of Alphanumeric code.

```
SELECT 'GC-01' "GroupCode", ITEM_NUMBER "Item" FROM ITEMS;
```

Is this something anyone can help with ?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42137625/generate-row-number-for-every-3-rows/42137853 could help in your scenario)

Comment: Take a look here, similar scenario in oracle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22414541/increment-value-on-column-every-n-records-on-table

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
select
    ITEM_NUMBER,
    1 + ( ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ITEM_NUMBER) - 1) / 5 as GROUP_NUMBER
from
    ITEMS
```

This gives you the Group Number you want; you can pad this with a leading zero if necessary, maybe using LPAD, and add a 'GC' to the beginning.

FYI, the ROW_NUMBER() function in this case is just providing a sequence number obtained by ordering the ITEM_NUMBERs alphabetically. We subtract 1 from it to make the sequence start at 0. We then divide this by 5 and the result gets rounded down to the nearest whole number - that gives us a distinct number for every 5 items (starting from 0, but you want it to start at 1 so we add 1 to the result).

Answer (score 0):

A query like the one below should give you a 5 items for each group code.  This will only print out group codes from GC-01 to GC-99. If you need a group number higher than 99, you will need to adjust the format mask.

```
WITH
    items (item)
    AS
        (SELECT 'ITEM-A' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'ITEM-B' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'ITEM-C' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'ITEM-D' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'ITEM-E' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'ITEM-F' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'ITEM-G' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'ITEM-H' FROM DUAL)
SELECT item, 'GC-' || TO_CHAR (CEIL (ROWNUM / 5), 'FM00') AS groupcode
  FROM items;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily on 12c and later like below:

```
select * from items
match_recognize
(
 order by item
 measures 'GC-'||to_char(match_number(),'fm00') as new_group_code
 all rows per match
 pattern ( a+ )
 define a as count(*) < = 5
);
```